# how to upload data to axios.post in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

There was a problem when transferring data to the redux toolkit for axios.post an error occurs

> Expected arguments: 0, received: 1.

Here is the redux code with the queries:

```
export const favoriteFetch = createAsyncThunk<IFavorite[]>(
    'favorite/favoriteFetch',
    async () => {
        const {data} = await axios.get<IFavorite[]>('http://localhost:3001/favorite');
        return data;
    }
) 

export const addFavoriteFetch = createAsyncThunk(
    'addFavorite/addFavoriteFetch',
    async (params) => {
        console.log(params)
        await axios.post<IFavorite[]>('http://localhost:3001/favorite', params);
    }
)
```

```
return (
    <div className={styles.contentProducts}>
        <img onClick={() => dispatch(addFavoriteFetch(({id, img, title, price})))} className={styles.contentProductsFavorite} src={favorite ? '/images/heartclick.png' : "/images/heart.png"} alt="" />
        <img className={styles.contentProductsImg} src={img} alt="" />
        <div className={styles.contentProductsOptions}>
            <div>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <div>Цена: {price} р.</div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(addProduct({id, img, title, price}))}>Добавить</button>  
        </div>
        
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a type for your `params`.

```
interface SomeParameterType {
  id: number;
  img: unknown;
  title: string;
  price: number;
}

export const addFavoriteFetch = createAsyncThunk(
  "addFavorite/addFavoriteFetch",
  async (params: SomeParameterType) => {
    console.log(params);
    await axios.post<IFavorite[]>("http://localhost:3001/favorite", params);
  }
);
```

Comment: It turned out to be so obvious, thank you very much.